# Why does SharePoint 2016 Copy option only show Base URL of the Library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, copy

Example: Click the ellipses next to a document twice and select copy.

The Copy window appears and only the base library URL appears in Destination.  Users are not happy manually appending a document library or folder location to the end of the base library URL.  Is this the only option?  Any plans to add a browse option? Do we have to upgrade to SharePoint 2019 or Modern to get the browse experience?  Is there a way to make the current document library/folder location appear in the destination window when selecting copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, this is currently the default behavior of classic experience, you may need to manually add the purpose Library yourself.

In fact, it is different in modern experience, you can choose the library by yourself instead of manually typing.

In order to let you see the difference more intuitively, I recorded a small video for you, you could compare the user experience in the two modes and choose whether to perform a migration.

However if the content you need to migrate is very large, the process may be a little time-consuming, so I would suggest to consider it carefully and then make a decision.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In SP2019 modern view, after you click `Copy To` or `Move To`, the right panel will prompt up and user can browse into subfolder (and to create subfolder here).

But you cannot select other libraries or site in the panel. The operation is limited to current library only.

In SharePoint online, the UI are the same but you can select other sites and libraries in the same tenant.